# memory leak when using CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, core-graphics

I use Instruments(Leaks) to detect memory leaks of my app. It sometimes says there is a memory leak in one of my methods. I am not sure whether there is a leak and how to solve it.

CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider method cause the memory leak mainly. Sometimes CGDataProviderCreateWithData also cause memory leak. But i don't know why.

The leak method in Class A is as follows:

```
- (ResultHolder *)decodeData:(UInt8 *) data withOffset:(int) offset {

    const int length = [IOUtilities byteArrayToIntWithData:data Offset:offset+18];
    UInt8 *buffer = malloc(length*sizeof(UInt8));
    memcpy(buffer, data+offset+22, length);

    // sometimes memory leak in this line
    CGDataProviderRef jpgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, length, freeData);

    // mainly memory leak in this line.
    CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(jpgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentSaturation);


    CGDataProviderRelease(jpgDataProvider);        
    ResultHolder *result = [[ResultHolder alloc] initWithCGImage:image];//sometimes memory leaks in this line.
    CGImageRelease(image);
    return result;
}
```

Also some other related methods:

```
// class A free buffer callback.
void freeData(void *info, const void *data, size_t size) {
    free((void *)data);
}
// class ReslutHolder init and dealloc.
- (id)initWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)image {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        CGImageRetain(image);

        //sometimes memory leak in this line.
        mBitmap = CGImageCreateCopy(image);

        mWidth = CGImageGetWidth(image);
        mHeight = CGImageGetHeight(image);
        CGImageRelease(image);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    if (mBitmap != NULL) {
        CGImageRelease(mBitmap);
        mBitmap = NULL;
    }
}
```

And I release mBitmap in the dealloc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not please try to use ARC

Comment: This are Quartz 2D objects... How does ARC help ?

Comment: I am using ARC. But as @mientus said,these methods are Quartz 2D objects.

Comment: Have you tried to run the static analyzer ?

Comment: @Geoffroy yes,i have tried the analyzer.its right for these methods.

Comment: @sch buffer is freed in freeData callback method. as to result, i am not sure, its NSObject subclass, ARC cannot work for that?

Comment: what is leaking? what kind of object?

Comment: @P-double CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(jpgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentSaturation); //mainly this line,sometimes other two lines, i noted in the code. ResultHolder is a class hold some image data. the decodeData method is decode the bytes to image data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can analyze the Memory Leaks in the Xcode using the analyzer as shown below

[image: Screenshot1]

Mentioning the memory leaks shown as below would help in further solving your problem

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: if you can see the leaks.. can you mention the leaks in your question

Comment: I go through Leaks->Extended Detail then double click the function name, it locate one line in the method, which mainly caused by CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider in my method.

Comment: can u mention what the memory leak shown by xcode (e.g. in my case **Value stored to 'copyView' during its initialization is never used**)

Comment: I use analyzer,it says the methods are all right. When i use leaks of instruments, sometimes, it shows me memory leaks of the method. you know, the leaks only locate the line of leak, no others.

Answer (score 0):

You should free the memory you allocated for your buffer.

```
free(buffer);
```

Comment: I free the buffer in freeData callback method.