# iPA file not working like it should when i build it

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipa

I have created an ipa file and i am trying to test it with devices. However it works fine when i install it from my code (using xcode) although when i install the ipa file directly using itunes the app works sometimes crashes other times. This i dont know how to debug. I dont know why it works differently as well.. I am using the development profile (i think) to create the ipa file too. SO is this the issue? If so should it not crash entirely as opposed to functioning sometimes and not the other times? Any help greatly appreciated. thanks

Crash log attached

```
   Incident Identifier: 7BAF9733-5E1C-4B11-97A2-6AF337514B60
   CrashReporter Key:   348b2ce3ff492f44d6260ffd552e63c6cfc21384
   Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
   Process:         x [661]
   Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/CA9BE7D9-BB3B-4FF8-8AE6-D60EEC2D3C9A/x.app/x
   Identifier:      x
   Version:         ??? (???)
   Code Type:       ARM (Native)
   Parent Process:  launchd [1]

   Date/Time:       2012-09-03 12:57:55.860 +0100
   OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B176)
   Report Version:  104

   Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
   Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x60000008
   Crashed Thread:  0

   Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
   Thread 0 Crashed:
   0   libobjc.A.dylib                  0x367a3f78 0x367a0000 + 16248
   1   UIKit                            0x32c85092 0x32ada000 + 1749138
   2   CoreFoundation                   0x31f577dc 0x31e9b000 + 772060
   3   CoreFoundation                   0x31eb27aa 0x31e9b000 + 96170
   4   CoreFoundation                   0x31eb23c8 0x31e9b000 + 95176
   5   WebKit                           0x32946e98 0x32938000 + 61080
   6   CoreFoundation                   0x31f56a7c 0x31e9b000 + 768636
   7   CoreFoundation                   0x31eb1648 0x31e9b000 + 91720
   8   CoreFoundation                   0x31f577dc 0x31e9b000 + 772060
   9   CoreFoundation                   0x31eb27aa 0x31e9b000 + 96170
   10  WebCore                          0x33779642 0x33715000 + 411202
   11  WebCore                          0x337795da 0x33715000 + 411098
   12  WebKit                           0x3294e1e0 0x32938000 + 90592
   13  WebKit                           0x32946a88 0x32938000 + 60040
   14  WebCore                          0x337d8672 0x33715000 + 800370
   15  WebCore                          0x3378e41a 0x33715000 + 496666
   16  WebCore                          0x3376edaa 0x33715000 + 368042
   17  WebCore                          0x337d9270 0x33715000 + 803440
   18  WebKit                           0x32947178 0x32938000 + 61816
   19  WebKit                           0x3294709c 0x32938000 + 61596
   20  UIKit                            0x32b6e688 0x32ada000 + 607880
   21  UIKit                            0x32b6e066 0x32ada000 + 606310
   22  CoreFoundation                   0x31f577dc 0x31e9b000 + 772060
   23  CoreFoundation                   0x31eb27aa 0x31e9b000 + 96170
   24  CoreFoundation                   0x31eb23c8 0x31e9b000 + 95176
   25  WebKit                           0x32946e98 0x32938000 + 61080
   26  CoreFoundation                   0x31f56a7c 0x31e9b000 + 768636
   27  CoreFoundation                   0x31eb1648 0x31e9b000 + 91720
   28  CoreFoundation                   0x31f577dc 0x31e9b000 + 772060
   29  CoreFoundation                   0x31eb27aa 0x31e9b000 + 96170
   30  WebCore                          0x33779642 0x33715000 + 411202
   31  WebCore                          0x3378cb3e 0x33715000 + 490302
   32  CoreFoundation                   0x31f28acc 0x31e9b000 + 580300
   33  CoreFoundation                   0x31f28298 0x31e9b000 + 578200
   34  CoreFoundation                   0x31f2703e 0x31e9b000 + 573502
   35  CoreFoundation                   0x31eaa49e 0x31e9b000 + 62622
   36  CoreFoundation                   0x31eaa366 0x31e9b000 + 62310
   37  GraphicsServices                 0x35908432 0x35904000 + 17458
   38  UIKit                            0x32b0be76 0x32ada000 + 204406
   39  x                                    0x0007d398 0x7c000 + 5016
   40  x                                        0x0007d350 0x7c000 + 4944


Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36cb63a8 0x36cb5000 + 5032
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x31e35f04 0x31e32000 + 16132
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x31e35c22 0x31e32000 + 15394

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36cc6068 0x36cb5000 + 69736
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31679a46 0x3166b000 + 59974
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31680574 0x3166b000 + 87412
3   WebCore                         0x337794b8 0x33715000 + 410808
4   WebKit                          0x32946d80 0x32938000 + 60800
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31f56a7c 0x31e9b000 + 768636
6   CoreFoundation                  0x31eb1648 0x31e9b000 + 91720
7   WebKit                          0x32954ec0 0x32938000 + 118464
8   WebCore                         0x337ee1ac 0x33715000 + 889260
9   WebCore                         0x337ee122 0x33715000 + 889122
10  WebCore                         0x337ee0dc 0x33715000 + 889052
11  WebCore                         0x337ee086 0x33715000 + 888966
12  WebKit                          0x32954c9a 0x32938000 + 117914
13  WebKit                          0x32954b10 0x32938000 + 117520
14  WebKit                          0x32954a48 0x32938000 + 117320
15  WebCore                         0x337eae9c 0x33715000 + 876188
16  WebCore                         0x337eae08 0x33715000 + 876040
17  WebCore                         0x337eaa2e 0x33715000 + 875054
18  WebCore                         0x337ea9ba 0x33715000 + 874938
19  WebCore                         0x337e9736 0x33715000 + 870198
20  WebCore                         0x337e90dc 0x33715000 + 868572
21  WebCore                         0x3397a232 0x33715000 + 2511410
22  WebCore                         0x3376ad1c 0x33715000 + 351516
23  WebCore                         0x3376ac8e 0x33715000 + 351374
24  CoreFoundation                  0x31f28a2c 0x31e9b000 + 580140
25  CoreFoundation                  0x31f28692 0x31e9b000 + 579218
26  CoreFoundation                  0x31f27268 0x31e9b000 + 574056
27  CoreFoundation                  0x31eaa49e 0x31e9b000 + 62622
28  CoreFoundation                  0x31eaa366 0x31e9b000 + 62310
29  WebCore                         0x337be0f0 0x33715000 + 692464
30  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3167972e 0x3166b000 + 59182
31  libsystem_c.dylib               0x316795e8 0x3166b000 + 58856

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36cb6004 0x36cb5000 + 4100
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36cb61fa 0x36cb5000 + 4602
2   CoreFoundation                  0x31f283ec 0x31e9b000 + 578540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31f27124 0x31e9b000 + 573732
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31eaa49e 0x31e9b000 + 62622
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31eaa366 0x31e9b000 + 62310
6   Foundation                      0x34ef1bb2 0x34ee1000 + 68530
7   Foundation                      0x34ef1a7a 0x34ee1000 + 68218
8   Foundation                      0x34f8558a 0x34ee1000 + 673162
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3167972e 0x3166b000 + 59182
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x316795e8 0x3166b000 + 58856

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36cc6cd4 0x36cb5000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31673f36 0x3166b000 + 36662
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31673cc8 0x3166b000 + 36040

Thread 5 name:  AQClient
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36cb6004 0x36cb5000 + 4100
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36cb61fa 0x36cb5000 + 4602
2   CoreFoundation                  0x31f283ec 0x31e9b000 + 578540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31f27124 0x31e9b000 + 573732
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31eaa49e 0x31e9b000 + 62622
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31eaa366 0x31e9b000 + 62310
6   AudioToolbox                    0x374c6b28 0x3744c000 + 502568
7   AudioToolbox                    0x3744dc9c 0x3744c000 + 7324
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3167972e 0x3166b000 + 59182
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x316795e8 0x3166b000 + 58856

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36cc6cd4 0x36cb5000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31673f36 0x3166b000 + 36662
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31673cc8 0x3166b000 + 36040

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36cc6570 0x36cb5000 + 71024
1   CoreFoundation                  0x31f2c63a 0x31e9b000 + 595514
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3167972e 0x3166b000 + 59182
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x316795e8 0x3166b000 + 58856

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36cc6cd4 0x36cb5000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31673f36 0x3166b000 + 36662
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31673cc8 0x3166b000 + 36040
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36cc6cd4 0x36cb5000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31673f36 0x3166b000 + 36662
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31673cc8 0x3166b000 + 36040

Thread 10 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
 Thread 10:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x36cb6004 0x36cb5000 + 4100
 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x36cb61fa 0x36cb5000 + 4602
 2   CoreFoundation                 0x31f283ec 0x31e9b000 + 578540
 3   CoreFoundation                 0x31f27124 0x31e9b000 + 573732
 4   CoreFoundation                 0x31eaa49e 0x31e9b000 + 62622
 5   CoreFoundation                 0x31eaa366 0x31e9b000 + 62310
 6   WebCore                        0x337e7526 0x33715000 + 861478
 7   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3167972e 0x3166b000 + 59182
 8   libsystem_c.dylib              0x316795e8 0x3166b000 + 58856

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
r0: 0x0c633e60    r1: 0x35c414f6      r2: 0x32eeedde      r3: 0x0c621080
r4: 0x60000000    r5: 0x0c683630      r6: 0x3f300b20      r7: 0x2fe79848
r8: 0x3f3107b8    r9: 0x0d71053d     r10: 0x3f310804     r11: 0x00000000
ip: 0x3f283048    sp: 0x2fe7982c      lr: 0x32c85099      pc: 0x367a3f78
cpsr: 0x200f0030
```

Comment: Do you get any crash logs? Please provide one in that case.

Comment: Is your code ARC enabled? Check if there is some memory leaks in the code using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211158/memory-leak-when-using-cgimagecreatewithjpegdataprovider/12211965#12211965).

Comment: _WebKit_ appears in the trace - are you using a UIWebView? And if you are, have you remembered to set it's delegate to `nil` after you are done with it? (See docs here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/delegate)

Comment: You should try if you have the crash log [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883069/how-to-decode-a-dsym-file-crash-log

Comment: Thanks to everyone. i solved the issue now also setting the delegate to nil in the viewdidunload method.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, then share the solution accept it so that it will help others in future.